# How to reference a sheet (which i dont know the name) name comes from a cell refernce

Tags: vba, macros

```
Sub New_Code

Dim exists as Boolean

For a = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(a).Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("V2") Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next a

If Not exists Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("V2")
End If
wk1.Sheets("Ab").Activate               wk1.Sheets("Ab").Range("A1:CK70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("V2").Value).Activate                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("V2")).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Need to pick sheet name written a Cell and reference that in the VBA Code to paste data the refrenced sheet name

Answer (score 0):

Dim sh As Worksheet, shNam As String
shNam = ActiveSheet.range("A1").Value

```
    Sheets(shNam).Activate
```

Comment: A few lines of explanation will make this a better answer. I recommend you read the Help section to learn how to better ask and answer questions here.